# How to use Spring to get the value of an Enum

Tags: java, spring, enums

```xml
<bean id="xyz" class="com.abc" >
  <property name="name">
    <bean         
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.FieldRetrievingFactoryBean">
        <property name="staticField" value="com.abc.staticname" />
     </bean>
   </property>
</bean>
```

This is the way previously I used to set the name of class com.abc. Now, the names should come from another enum. How do I access the enum value to set the name property of my class com.abc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see why you can't keep on using [FieldRetrievingFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/FieldRetrievingFactoryBean.html), that's what it's for.

It's a little bit easier to use than your example suggests, though. Also, there's the easier schema-based syntax which does the same thing, `<util:constant>`.

Both approaches are documented (and compared) [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-constant).

(Remember that enum values are just static fields on the enum class)

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the enum name as the value, and Spring will automatically detect that it's a static field of the enum type and use it. So for example, if you have an enum com.mycompany.MyEnum with values SOMEVAL, ANOTHERVAL, you can use :

```xml
<property name="myEnumProperty" value="SOMEVAL" />
```

This will allow you to avoid FieldRetrievingFactoryBean and `<util:constant>` altogether.